# How to obtain data from random wikipedia page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$(".wikiResult h3").load("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random #firstHeading i");`

I would like to obtain the title of a random Wikipedia article.

The Wikipedia URL in the code above redirects to a random article, which is ideally where I would like to receive data from.

Unfortunately, due to the redirect, I receive a CORS policy error; which prevents me from receiving any data.

Is there a way in which I am able to obtain the redirected URL first, and then use this to retrieve my data, using only vanilla Javascript and/or jQuery?

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js

Comment: Please take care of your spelling and Grammar to make it easier for folks to understand your question. This way it is more likely for you to get the desired answer.

Comment: can you elaborate on "my link redirects to another link which I want to receive data from, CORS policy error occurs" ? Are you saying you can't access wikipedia because you are getting CORS problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the API would probably be your best bet. The key piece you are missing is the query parameter `origin=*` From [Cross Site Requests](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests)

> Unauthenticated CORS requests may be made from any origin by setting the "origin" request parameter to "*".

so to get the JSON data of a random page using jQuery's `load()` you could do

```
$(".wikiResult h3").load("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&format=json&action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=revisions|images&rvprop=content");
```

or better yet, do a GET request and parse the response JSON for the title

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&format=json&action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=revisions|images&rvprop=content",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(getTitle(data));
  },
  error: function(xhr, error) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(error);
  }
});

function getTitle(data) {
  let pages = data.query.pages;
  let firstKey = Object.keys(pages)[0];
  return pages[firstKey].title;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wikiResult"></div>
```